# How can I easily edit after finding text in Sublime Text 3?

Tags: sublimetext3, sublimetext2

Whenever I do a sublime find, at some match I wish to add the text. But is there a shortcut to edit without moving mouse and clicking the text (to bring cursor to that location)

Example gif (issue I'm facing) - https://i.stack.imgur.com/4LNaG.jpg

Answer (score 1):

Just press `Esc` after finding your text.